# requests.get not returning html similar to browser's devtools

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using beautifulsoup and requests to scrape a website but I am not getting proper html.
This is kind of what I am getting (removed some link tags from head):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  html dir="ltr" lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>
  .... title was here ...
  </title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
   <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
    <link href="/img/logo.png" rel="icon" type="image/png"/>   </link>
 </head>
 <style>
  form.search-form {
    display: block;
}
li, ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#header {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 997;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgb(18, 18, 18);
    position: fixed;
}
.containerv {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.containerv:before, .nav:before, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-collapse:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
#rowheader {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#top-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    margin: 6px 0 0 -32.5px;
}
.logo-animated {
    animation-name: Breathing2;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.logo-animated.img {
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background: url(/img/logon.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.logo-animated.img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px #53bbf4); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px #53bbf4);
}
.content-header-bottom {
    border-left: 65px solid transparent;
    border-right: 65px solid transparent;
    border-top: 36.6px solid rgb(18, 18, 18);
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.info-not {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: #333333;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -3;
}
.navbar-nav.brand-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 130px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.nav-random {
    position: fixed;
    top: 11px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
svg.n {
    fill: #e8e5d3;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
}
.info-not ol {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}
.info-not ol li {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 40px;
    background: #333333;
}
.not {
    margin-left: 147px;
}
.info-not ol li:first-child a {
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.info-not ol li a {
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    letter-spacing: -.7px;
    padding-left: 28px;
    position: relative;
    background: #333333;
}
.info-not ol li:last-child a {
    background: 0 0;
    margin-left: 1px;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: #333333;
}
svg.footer path {
    fill: #2e2e2e;
}
.info-not ol li a.noti:before {
    border: solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #121212;
    border-width: 20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.info-not ol li a.noti:after {
    border: solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #333333;
    border-width: 20px;
    left: -1px;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.main {
    max-width: 1080px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu{
    display: none;
}
.route {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
nav.sidebar-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    left: 0;
    top: 79.5px;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 100%;
    background: #070707;
    color: #fafafa;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: translate(-100%,0);
    transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(0.77,.2,.05,1);
    z-index: 998;
}
.sidebar-content {
    max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
li.header-menu {
    margin: .1em 0;
}
.sidebar-menu ul li a span {
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
li.header-menu span {
    color: #eeedeb;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.sidebar-menu ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 30px 8px 20px;
}
nav.sidebar-wrapper.show {
    transform: scale(1,1);
}
.searchModal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.73);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);
}
.sm-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);
    width: 98%;
    left: 1%;
    height: 0%;
    top: 1%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}
.close, .searc {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    background: #e7e7e7;
}
.ads-module {
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 475px;
    background-color: #23201d;
    border: 2px solid #594d42;
}
.close {
    margin: 8px;
}
.close svg, .searc svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
button.searc svg {
    fill: #171717;
}
.close svg {
    background: #171717;
        fill: #e7e7e7;
}
form#search-form {
    text-align: left;
    color: #cbcbcb;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7!important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-top: 1px solid #3a3939;
    border-left: 1px solid #3a3939;
    border-right: 1px solid #3a3939;
}
.input-group {
    padding: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
input#search-input {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e7e7e7!important;
    height: 100%;
}
.searchModal.active * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sea-fle, .input-group {
    display: flex;
}
.sea-fle {
        background-color: #1e4459;
    border: 2px solid #4CADE1;
    padding: 15px;

}
.searchModal.active {
    height: 100%;
}
.searchModal.active>.sm-content {
    height: 98%;
    padding: 40px 200px;
}
@media (max-width: 960px) {
#main-nav, .nav-random, .info-not ol li {
    display: none;
}
a.menu {
    color: #e5e5d3;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 2.5rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 3.25rem;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.menu span:first-child {
    background-color: currentColor;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    left: calc(50% - 8px);
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition-duration: 86ms;
    transition-property: background-color,opacity,transform,-webkit-transform;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    width: 16px;
    top: calc(50% - 6px);
}
.menu span:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: currentColor;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    left: calc(50% - 8px);
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition-duration: 86ms;
    transition-property: background-color,opacity,transform,-webkit-transform;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    width: 16px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
}
.menu span:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: currentColor;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    left: calc(50% - 8px);
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition-duration: 86ms;
    transition-property: background-color,opacity,transform,-webkit-transform;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    width: 16px;
    top: calc(50% + 4px);
}
.menu.active span:first-child {
   

similar format continues .....
```

I am expecting a `body` tag after `head`. While in chrome devtools it shows ok.
I searched it and first thought `{'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}` is making the format like this. But I changed my code and added `{'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}` to headers.
But the problem still persisted.
And I also read somewhere that requests library can not automatically deal with gzip.

These are the headers:

```
{'Date': 'Sun, 11 Oct 2020 09:24:27 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d2c982fbe3f6d64b1b4d3a8be7080e90c1602408267; expires=Tue, 10-Nov-20 09:24:27 GMT; path=/; domain=.pantsubase.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure, 
PHPSESSID=4e41d27d1428d26da658a9b0e5c0b9ae; path=/', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate', 'Cf-Railgun': 'd561de73b9 stream 0.000000 0210 c794', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'cf-request-id': '05b892d7720000e664e71a7200000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Report-To': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report?lkg-colo=21&lkg-time=1602408268"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}', 'NEL': '{"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '5e078738bc97e664-LHR', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'alt-svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong or not doing at all?

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: https://old.pantsubase.com/watch/203230-digimon-adventure-episode-19-english-sub

Comment: Please keep in mind that if the site's content is dynamic, you will not be able to access it using requests.

Comment: Yeah I understood that now. I'll have to use selenium or something, but it is slow. I think in this case I can get that second document by only requests . Can I?  I don't know really, So I'll try this and if nothing happens, I'll use something else. Any further help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify other parser (`lxml` or `html5lib` when you're creating the soup). It seems that the markup on that page is "broken":

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://old.pantsubase.com/watch/203230-digimon-adventure-episode-19-english-sub'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'lxml')

print(soup.body)
```

Comment: This worked. But I used both parsers earlier. Its soup.body that worked. I was printing just soup.prettify    Can you please tell why that does not show while soup.body does

Comment: @hac_ticc What version of `bs4` are you using? When I use `soup.prettify()` I can see the `<body>` tag. Maybe you can run [`diagnose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose) function on your markup.

Comment: I thought that was problem, so I already updated bs4 and requests before asking question.  And I will try diagnose()

Comment: @hac_ticc this `<div id="video">` tag is created dynamically via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. I recommend to look at `selenium` - this will execute Javascript and you will be able to download the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `user-agent` to the request that you make, like:

```
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}

r = requests.get('https://old.pantsubase.com/watch/203230-digimon-adventure-episode-19-english-sub',headers = headers)

print(r.content)
```

Output:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en" dir="ltr">\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Watch Digimon Adventure: Episode 19 English Sub : Pantsubase \xe2\x98\x85 Moe Moe, Kyun!</title>\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">\n<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />\n<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />\n<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">\n<meta name="theme-color" content="#53bbf4">\n<script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/zYR5uwvdEStbpZyYVe_i8NIfIRw.js"></script><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logo.png" />\n<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">\n<link id="theme-changer" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">\n<script src="/js/kuroani.js"></script>\n<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">\n<link rel="image_src" href="" />\n<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://pantsubase.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/iphone5_splash.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/iphone6_splash.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/iphoneplus_splash.png" media="(device-width: 621px) and (device-height: 1104px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/iphonex_splash.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/iphonexr_splash.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/iphonexsmax_splash.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/ipad_splash.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/ipadpro1_splash.png" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/ipadpro3_splash.png" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link href="https://pantsubase.com/splashscreens/ipadpro2_splash.png" media="(device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">\n<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />\n<script async src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/GoogleChrome/pwacompat/v2.0.1/pwacompat.min.js"></script>\n</head>\n<style>\nform.search-form {\n    display: block;\n}\nli, ol {\n    list-style-type: none;\n}\n#header {\n    top: 0;\n    z-index: 997;\n    width: 100%;\n    height: 40px;\n    background: rgb(18, 18, 18);\n    position: fixed;\n}\n.containerv {\n    margin-right: auto;\n    margin-left: auto;\n    padding-left: 15px;\n    padding-right: 15px;\n}\n.containerv:before, .nav:before, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-collapse:before {\n    content: " ";\n    display: table;\n}\n#rowheader {\n    width: 100%;\n    margin: 0;\n    position: relative;\n}\n#top-brand {\n    position: absolute;\n    left: 60px;\n    margin: 6px 0 0 -32.5px;\n}\n.logo-animated {\n    animation-name: Breathing2;\n    animation-duration: 3s;\n    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;\n}\n.logo-animated.img {\n    width: 60px;\n    border-radius: 60px;\n    overflow: hidden;\n    margin-left: 10px;\n    height: 80px;\n    margin-top: -10px;\n    background: url(/img/logon.png);\n    background-size: 100% 100%;\n    background-repeat: no-repeat;\n}\n.logo-animated.img:hover {\n    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px #53bbf4); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */\n    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px #53bbf4);\n}\n.content-header-bottom {\n    border-left: 65px solid transparent;\n    border-right: 65px solid transparent;\n    border-top: 36.6px solid rgb(18, 18, 18);\n    position: absolute;\n    top: 38px;\n    z-index: -1;\n    margin-left: auto;\n    margin-right: auto;\n}\n.info-not {\n    margin-top: 40px;\n    width: 100%;\n    height: 40px;\n    float: left;\n    background: #333333;\n    overflow: hidden;\n    z-index: -3;\n}\n.navbar-nav.brand-left {\n    position: absolute;\n    left: 130px;\n    margin-right: 60px;\n    margin-top: 0;\n}\n.navbar-nav>li {\n    float: left;\n    position: relative;\n    display: inline-flex;\n}\n.navbar-nav>li>a {\n    padding: 10px 15px;\n    font-size: 15px;\n    transition: opacity .5s ease;\n    font-weight: 700;\n}\n.nav-random {\n    position: fixed;\n    top: 11px;\n    right: 10px;\n    z-index: 11;\n    width: 24px;\n    height: 24px;\n}\nsvg.n {\n    fill: #e8e5d3;\n    height: 18px;\n    width: 18px;\n}\n.info-not ol {\n    width: auto;\n    float: left;\n    height: 40px;\n}\n.info-not ol li {\n    width: auto;\n    float: left;\n    list-style: none;\n    height: 40px;\n    background: #333333;\n}\n.not {\n    margin-left: 147px;\n}\n.info-not ol li:first-child a {\n    padding: 0 15px;\n    font-weight: 700;\n    font-size: 13px;\n}\n.info-not ol li a {\n    height: 40px;\n    float: left;\n    color: #fff;\n    font-size: 15px;\n    line-height: 40px;\n    padding: 0 10px;\n    letter-spacing: -.7px;\n    padding-left: 28px;\n    position: relative;\n    background: #333333;\n}\n.info-not ol li:last-child a {\n    background: 0 0;\n    margin-left: 1px;\n    transition: opacity .5s ease;\n    font-weight: 700;\n    letter-spacing: 1px;\n    background: #333333;\n}\nsvg.footer path {\n    fill: #2e2e2e;\n}\n.info-not ol li a.noti:before {\n    border: solid transparent;\n    border-left-color: #121212;\n    border-width: 20px;\n    left: 0;\n    top: 0;\n    content: \'\';\n    position: absolute;\n    height: 0;\n    width: 0;\n}\n.info-not ol li a.noti:after {\n    border: solid transparent;\n    border-left-color: #333333;\n    border-width: 20px;\n    left: -1px;\n    top: 0;\n    content: \'\';\n    position: absolute;\n    height: 0;\n    width: 0;\n}\n.main {\n    max-width: 1080px;\n    overflow: hidden;\n    width: 100%;\n    margin: 0 auto;\n}\n.menu{\n    display: none;\n}\n.route {\n    font-size: 13px;\n    line-height: 30px;\n}\nnav.sidebar-wrapper {\n    position: fixed;\n    width: 250px;\n    left: 0;\n    top: 79.5px;\n    padding: 1rem;\n    height: 100%;\n    background: #070707;\n    color: #fafafa;\n    overflow-x: hidden;\n    overflow-y: auto;\n    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;\n    transform-origin: 0 0;\n    transform: translate(-100%,0);\n    transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(0.77,.2,.05,1);\n    z-index: 998;\n}\n.sidebar-content {\n    max-height: calc(100% - 30px);\n    height: calc(100% - 30px);\n    overflow-y: auto;\n    position: relative;\n}\nli.header-menu {\n    margin: .1em 0;\n}\n.sidebar-menu ul li a span {\n    padding: 8px;\n    font-size: 16px;\n}\nli.header-menu span {\n    color: #eeedeb;\n    display: inline-block;\n    padding: 10px 15px;\n    font-size: 16px;\n    transition: opacity .5s ease;\n    font-weight: 700;\n}\n.sidebar-menu ul li a {\n    display: inline-block;\n    width: 100%;\n    text-decoration: none;\n    position: relative;\n    padding: 8px 30px 8px 20px;\n}\nnav.sidebar-wrapper.show {\n    transform: scale(1,1);\n}\n.searchModal {\n    width: 100%;\n    height: 0%;\n    position: fixed;\n    left: 0;\n    top: 0;\n    overflow: hidden;\n    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;\n    transform-origin: 100% 0;\n    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;\n    transition-duration: .5s;\n    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);\n    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);\n    z-index: 999;\n    bottom: 0;\n    background: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.73);\n    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;\n    transform-origin: 100% 0;\n    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;\n    transition-duration: .5s;\n    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);\n    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);\n}\n.sm-content {\n    overflow: hidden;\n    position: fixed;\n    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;\n    transform-origin: 100% 0;\n    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;\n    transition-duration: .5s;\n    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);\n    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,0,.3,1);\n    width: 98%;\n    left: 1%;\n    height: 0%;\n    top: 1%;\n    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;\n    transition-delay: .4s;\n}\n.close, .searc {\n    width: 20px;\n    height: 20px;\n    cursor: pointer;\n    border: 0;\n    background: #e7e7e7;\n}\n.ads-module {\n    margin-top: 10px;\n    overflow: hidden;\n    width: 100%;\n    padding: 10px;\n    height: 475px;\n    background-color: #23201d;\n    border: 2px solid #594d42;\n}\n.close {\n    margin: 8px;\n}\n.close svg, .searc svg {\n    width: 100%;\n    height: 100%;\n}\nbutton.searc svg {\n    fill: #171717;\n}\n.close svg {\n    background: #171717;\n\tfill: #e7e7e7;\n}\nform#search-form {\n    text-align: left;\n    color: #cbcbcb;\n    border: 0;\n    width: 100%;\n    background: #fff;\n    overflow: hidden;\n    margin: 0;\n    height: 36px;\n    background-color: #e7e7e7!important;\n    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;\n    border-top: 1px solid #3a3939;\n    border-left: 1px solid #3a3939;\n    border-right: 1px solid #3a3939;\n}\n.input-group {\n    padding: 6px;\n    width: 100%;\n    height: 100%;\n}\ninput#search-input {\n    border: 0;\n    width: 100%;\n    border-radius: 5px;\n    overflow: hidden;\n    background-color: #e7e7e7!important;\n    height: 100%;\n}\n.searchModal.active * {\n    box-sizing: border-box;\n}\n.sea-fle, .input-group {\n    display: flex;\n}\n.sea-fle {\n\tbackground-color: #1e4459;\n    border: 2px solid #4CADE1;\n    padding: 15px;\n    \n}\n.searchModal.active {\n    height: 100%;\n}\n.searchModal.active>.sm-content {\n    height: 98%;\n    padding: 40px 200px;\n}\n@media (max-width: 960px) {\n#main-nav, .nav-random, .info-not ol li {\n    display: none;\n}\na.menu {\n    color: #e5e5d3;\n    cursor: pointer;\n    display: block;\n    height: 2.5rem;\n    position: relative;\n    width: 3.25rem;\n    margin-left: auto;\n}\n.menu span:first-child {\n    background-color: currentColor;\n    display: block;\n    height: 1px;\n    left: calc(50% - 8px);\n    position: absolute;\n    transform-origin: center;\n    transition-duration: 86ms;\n    transition-property: background-color,opacity,transform,-webkit-transform;\n    transition-timing-function: ease-out;\n    width: 16px;\n    top: calc(50% - 6px);\n}\n.menu span:nth-child(2) {\n    background-color: currentColor;\n    display: block;\n    height: 1px;\n    left: calc(50% - 8px);\n    position: absolute;\n    transform-origin: center;\n    transition-duration: 86ms;\n    transition-property: background-color,opacity,transform,-webkit-transform;\n    transition-timing-function: ease-out;\n    width: 16px;\n    opacity: 1;\n    top: calc(50% - 1px);\n}\n.menu span:nth-child(3) {\n    background-color: currentColor;\n    display: block;\n    height: 1px;\n    left: calc(50% - 8px);\n    position: absolute;\n    transform-origin: center;\n    transition-duration: 86ms;\n    transition-property: background-color,opacity,transform,-webkit-transform;\n    transition-timing-function: ease-out;\n    width: 16px;\n    top: calc(50% + 4px);\n}\n.menu.active span:first-child {\n    transform: translateY(5px) rotate(45deg);\n}\n.menu.active span:nth-child(2) {\n    opacity: 0;\n}\n.menu.active span:nth-child(3) {\n    transform: translateY(-5px) rotate(-45deg);\n}\nfooter {\n    padding-left: 8px;\n    padding-right: 8px;\n}\nsvg.footer {\n    display: none;\n}\n.logoWrap-so {\n    display: -webkit-box;\n    display: -ms-flexbox;\n    display: flex;\n    margin: 16px 0;\n    width: 45%;\n}\na.logo-co {\n    margin: 0 auto;\n}\n.navigation {\n    -ms-flex-align: start;\n    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;\n    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;\n    -webkit-box-align: start;\n    -webkit-box-direction: normal;\n    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;\n    align-items: flex-start;\n    flex-flow: row wrap;\n    justify-content: space-around;\n}\n.navigationSection-con {\n    margin: 16px 0;\n    text-align: center;\n    width: 45%;\n}\n.searchModal.active>.sm-content {\n    padding: 40px 50px;\n}\n}\n@media (max-width: 550px) {\n.searchModal.active>.sm-content {\n    padding: 40px 20px;\n}\n}\n</style>\n<body class="list-me">\n<script>if (\'serviceWorker\' in navigator) {\n  // sw.js can literally be empty, but must exist\n  navigator.serviceWorker.register(\'/sw.js\');\n}\n\nfunction addToHomeScreen() {\n        let a2hsBtn = document.querySelector(".ad2hs-prompt");  // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button\n        a2hsBtn.style.display = \'none\';  // Show the prompt\n        deferredPrompt.prompt();  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt\n        deferredPrompt.userChoice\n          .then(function(choiceResult){\n        if (choiceResult.outcome === \'accepted\') {\n          console.log(\'User accepted the A2HS prompt\');\n        } else {\n          console.log(\'User dismissed the A2HS prompt\');\n        }\n        deferredPrompt = null;\n      });}\n      function showAddToHomeScreen() {\n        let a2hsBtn = document.querySelector(".ad2hs-prompt");\n        a2hsBtn.style.display = "block";\n        a2hsBtn.addEventListener("click", addToHomeScreen);\n      }\n      let deferredPrompt;\n      window.addEventListener(\'beforeinstallprompt\', function (e) {\n        // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt\n        e.preventDefault();\n        // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.\n        deferredPrompt = e;\n        showAddToHomeScreen();\n      });\n    \n      function showIosInstall() {\n        let iosPrompt = document.querySelector(".ios-prompt");\n        iosPrompt.style.display = "block";\n        iosPrompt.addEventListener("click", () => {\n          iosPrompt.style.display = "none";\n        });\n      }\n    \n      // Detects if device is on iOS\n      const isIos = () => {\n        const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();\n        return /iphone|ipad|ipod/.test( userAgent );\n      }\n      // Detects if device is in standalone mode\n      const isInStandaloneMode = () => (\'standalone\' in window.navigator) && (window.navigator.standalone);\n      // Checks if should display install popup notification:\n      if (isIos() && !isInStandaloneMode()) {\n        // this.setState({ showInstallMessage: true });\n        showIosInstall();\n      }\n</script>\n<div id="fb-root"></div>\n<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2&appId=400381637444503&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>\n<div id="header" class="containerv"><div id="rowheader" class="row vertical-center"><div id="top-brand"><a href="/"><div class="logo-animated"><div class="logo-animated img"></div></div></a></div><div class="content-header-bottom"></div><div id="main-nav"><ul class="nav navbar-nav brand-left"><li><a class="inactive-menu" href="/anime-list">Browse</a></li><li><a class="inactive-menu" href="/support">Support</a></li><li><a id="search" class="inactive-menu" href="#search">Search</a></li></ul></div><a class="nav-random" href="https://old.pantsubase.com/anime/3191-robomasters-the-animated-series"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="n"><path d="M17,3L22.25,7.5L17,12L22.25,16.5L17,21V18H14.26L11.44,15.18L13.56,13.06L15.5,15H17V12L17,9H15.5L6.5,18H2V15H5.26L14.26,6H17V3M2,6H6.5L9.32,8.82L7.2,10.94L5.26,9H2V6Z"></path></svg></a><a role="button" class="menu"><span></span> <span></span> <span></span></a></div></div>\n<div class="info-not">\n<ol>\n<li><a class="not" href="#notice">Notice</a></li>\n<li><a class="noti">Join our discord community, We recently just merged with A Shelter For Anime Lovers! </a></li>\n<li><a class="noti" href="https://discord.gg/zAnR33k"><i class="fab fa-discord" style="font-size:30px;color:#738adb;padding-top:5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>\n<li><a class="noti" href="https://pantsubase.com">Switch to New Pantsubase</a>\n</li>\n</ol>\n</div>\n<div class="clear"></div>\n<div class="content"><meta property="og:image" content="//cdn.animeapi.com/images/1/dcd384395f5d_352x220.jpg">\n<meta name="description" content="Watch online and download anime Digimon Adventure: Episode 19 english subbed/dubbed in high quality">\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/anime-episode.css">\n<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#server").click(function(){$(".server").toggleClass("show");});})</script>\n<style>.server.show{display: block;}</style>\n<script type="text/javascript" src=\'//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5b698620d5484b00116a8fdd&product=inline-share-buttons\' async=\'async\'></script>\n<div class="server"><div id="mirrors" class="dropdown-menu p-0" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1"></div></div>\n<div class="clear"></div>\n<div class="container">\n<div class="player-san">\n<div id="player" class="embed-container" style="min-height: 525"></div>\n<div class="player-menu">\n<div class="desd2">\n<div id="server"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> | <i class="fas fa-server"></i></a></div>\n<div id="refresh" data-index="0"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i> Refresh</div>\n</div>\n<div class="desd">\n<div class="desd3"><a class=\'btn btn-danger float-left\' href=\'https://old.pantsubase.com/watch/203151-digimon-adventure-episode-18-english-sub\'>Prev</a><a class=\'all-epi btn btn-danger float-left\' href=\'https://old.pantsubase.com/anime/4832-digimon-adventure\'><i class=\'fa fa-list-ol\'></i></a></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div style="\n    max-width: 480px;\n    width: 100%;\n    margin: 0 auto;\n">\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class="episo-detai">\n<div class="item meta">\n<div class="tb" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">\n<img width=\'350\' height=\'476\' src=\'https://cdn.animeapi.com/images/anime/4832.jpg\' class=\'attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image\' alt=\'\'> </div>\n<div class="lm">\n<h1 itemprop=\'name\'>Digimon Adventure: English Sub</h1><span class=\'epi-name\'><span class=\'epx\'>Episode 19</span> <span class=\'year\'>In the year 2020, technology is everywhere. Every digital device around the world is connected by a singular network where data travels. Unbeknownst to humans, this network has become home to life forms known as &#34;Digimon.&#34; Fifth-grader Taichi Yagami is preparing for summer camp when strange occurrences begin in Tokyo; certain electronic systems have started going haywire. When he discovers that his sister and mother are trapped on an unstoppable train, he rushes to the nearby station. Suddenly, Taichi is transported to another world where he meets a strange creature by the name of Agumon, who somehow already knows his name. Taichi also receives a strange device called a &#34;Digivice,&#34; which allows him to communicate with the undigitized world. Taichi discovers he is in the &#34;Network,&#34; and virus-like Digimon are attacking the areas that maintain Tokyo\xe2\x80\x99s electronic systems. It is up to Taichi and his new partner Agumon to stop these cyberattacks before the whole world is threatened by the actions of mischievous Digimon. [Written by MAL Rewrite]</span> </div>\n</div>\n<div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons" style="margin-top: 7px;"></div>\n<div id="fb-save-button"><div id="save-button" class="fb-save" data-uri="https://old.pantsubase.com/watch/203230-digimon-adventure-episode-19-english-sub" data-size="large"></div></div>\n<style>\ndiv#fb-save-button {\n    margin: auto;\n    margin-top: 5px;\n    margin-bottom: 5px;\n    width: 150px;\n}</style>\n</div>\n</div>\n<script type=\'text/javascript\'>var episode_videos = [{"host":"trollvid","id":"dcd384395f5d","type":"subbed","date":"2020-10-11 04:50:05"},{"host":"vidstreaming","id":"MTQ2Mjk2","type":"subbed","date":"2020-10-11 04:50:03"}];</script>\n<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>\n<script type=\'text/javascript\' src="/js/anime-controls.js?11"></script>\n<script type=\'text/javascript\' src="/js/pagination.min.js"></script>\n</div>\n<nav class="sidebar-wrapper">\n<div class="sidebar-content">\n<div class="sidebar-menu">\n<ul>\n<li class="header-menu">\n<span>General</span>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href="/anime-list">\n<span>Browse</span>\n</a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href="/ongoing-anime">\n<span>Ongoing</span>\n</a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href="https://old.pantsubase.com/anime/2746-jungle-wa-itsumo-hare-nochi-guu">\n<span>Random</span>\n</a>\n</li>\n<li class="search-menu">\n<a id="search-con" href="#search">\n<span>Search</span>\n</a>\n</li>\n<li class="header-menu">\n<span>Extra</span>\n</li>\n<li class="header-menu">\n<span>Social Networks</span>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href="https://discord.gg/5tm4C2M">\n<span>Discord</span>\n</a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pantsubesu/">\n<span>Facebook</span>\n</a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/pantsubase/">\n<span>Join our Group</span>\n</a>\n</li>\n</ul>\n</div>\n</div>\n</nav>\n<div class="searchModal">\n<div class="sm-content">\n<div class="sea-fle">\n<form action="/search" method="GET" id="search-form" class="search-form">\n<div class="input-group">\n<input type="text" class="form-control" name="term" id="search-input" placeholder="Search Anime.." aria-label="Search for...">\n<button class="searc" type="submit">\n<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M13.262,14.868l2.479,2.478c-0.376,0.725-0.415,1.445-0.017,1.843l4.525,4.526 c0.571,0.571,1.812,0.257,2.768-0.7c0.956-0.955,1.269-2.195,0.697-2.766l-4.524-4.526c-0.399-0.398-1.119-0.36-1.842,0.016 l-2.48-2.478L13.262,14.868z M8.5,0C3.806,0,0,3.806,0,8.5C0,13.194,3.806,17,8.5,17S17,13.194,17,8.5C17,3.806,13.194,0,8.5,0z M8.5,15C4.91,15,2,12.09,2,8.5S4.91,2,8.5,2S15,4.91,15,8.5S12.09,15,8.5,15z"></path></svg>\n</button>\n</div>\n</form>\n<div class="close"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 21.9 21.9" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 21.9 21.9">\n<path d="M14.1,11.3c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5,0-0.7l7.5-7.5c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.3-0.7s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7l-1.4-1.4C20,0.1,19.7,0,19.5,0  c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.3l-7.5,7.5c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.2-0.7,0L3.1,0.3C2.9,0.1,2.6,0,2.4,0S1.9,0.1,1.7,0.3L0.3,1.7C0.1,1.9,0,2.2,0,2.4  s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l7.5,7.5c0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5,0,0.7l-7.5,7.5C0.1,19,0,19.3,0,19.5s0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7l1.4,1.4c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.3  s0.5-0.1,0.7-0.3l7.5-7.5c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.7,0l7.5,7.5c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.3s0.5-0.1,0.7-0.3l1.4-1.4c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.3-0.7  s-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7L14.1,11.3z" />\n</svg></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class="bar">\n<div class="container-dark">\n<div class="theme quicktoggler">\n<span class="text">Change theme</span>\n<div class="bwbox" id="bbox" onclick="changeTheme()">\n<div class="bwselect" id="bwsel"></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<footer class="foot">\n<div class="foot-con">\nAll Rights Reserved Pantsubase Inc.\n<script>\n            $( document ).ready(function() {\n $( ".menu" ).click(function() {$( ".sidebar-wrapper" )\n .toggleClass( "show" );});});\n $( document ).ready(function() {\n $( ".menu" ).click(function() {$( ".menu" )\n .toggleClass( "active" );});});\n$(\'#search\').click(function(){\n    $(\'.searchModal\').addClass(\'active\')\n});\n$(\'#search-con\').click(function(){\n    $(\'.searchModal\').addClass(\'active\')\n});\n$(\'.close\').click(function(){\n    $(\'.searchModal\').removeClass(\'active\')\n});\n        </script>\n</footer>\n<script src="/js/theme.js"></script>\n<script type=\'text/javascript\' src="/js/controls.js?v=.0005">\n  </body>\n</html>'
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I have already added User-Agent. Without user-agent it was giving 403 forbidden.

Comment: Oh...Okay. BTW, what do u wanna scrape from the website?

Comment: I was just learning scraping and was just trying to get video url. Its not anything specific though.